# dynamically select appconfig in vue

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I know that you can create .env.xxxx files in vue and then run a dev, test and production builds to have environment specific environmental variables.

But what if I want to do one build and then when the app is running it could dynamically select the app config file based on the environment the app is hosted in. It's given that the host environment could have VUE_APP_ENVIRONMENT environmental variable and could use this to decide what settings to use.

What's a good way to do this?

Comment: Have you checked webpack's environment plugin? From what you've described (and I understood) this could be a direction to go: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/

Comment: Is webpack for compile time decision making? I want one compile and decisions to choose environment / app settings at run time. Maybe I could but the app-setting in the public folder and get the deploy agent to ensure the correct settings are copied in